# interface blocking when answering the phone on a Sony Experia U

Tags: user-interface

I am experiencing a weird behavior with my Sony Experia U 
didn't happen before,

When someone calls me I answer my phone and the interface gets stuck after swiping the answer button, it continues to vibrate or ring...
the other party hears everything but I can't take action only after like 4 vibrates time 
so 3,4 seconds...

It's very annoying....

I use android 4.2.2  with the original firmware from sony..

I looked if I have some weird widgets or installed apps ..none...

Comment: I remember a similar issue years back on Eclair with one of my devices. Flashing a new (updated) radio firmware image (provided by the manufacturer) solved the issue then. You might want to ask your service contact for that.

Comment: is this something that can be done with the pc software ? i am a pretty computer wise guy ..so unless I need some unblocking codes I can reflash it

Comment: Too long ago for me, but yes. If I remember correctly, it's nothing more than placing an `update.zip` on your SDCard, and flash it from recovery. Trick is to find the `update.zip`. [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) might be a good starting point on that, too, as often RUUs are mentioned along the ROMs.